# Application keyboard shortcuts

Tags: cyanogenmod, keyboard-shortcuts

In CM7 (now running CM9 on my EVO 4G) there was an option somewhere in the settings to set keyboard shortcuts (I think it was limited to `Search+[key]` combinations). I loved using this with my Bluetooth keyboard, for example using "Status Bar Expander" to be able to see my notifications by only using the keyboard.

However, in CM9, I can no longer find this option. Does anyone know where it went or how to get this functionality otherwise?

**Update**: I've found [this (quite useful) list](http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-1459364.html), but I would still like to know if I can edit/add these key combos.

> ESC: Back (woo!)
>
> Targus FN + F* keys: (edit: These only work with the specific model of
>   Targus keyboard. Your FN key may only perform functions as labelled,
>   test it to verify)
>
> FN+F1: Search
>
> FN+F8: play/pause music
>
> FN+F7: Skip Prev
>
> FN+F9: Skip Next
>
> FN+F11: Volume -
>
> FN+F12: Volume +
>
> FN+ESC: Wallpaper, manage apps, system settings.
>
> Alt+Tab - recent apps, task switcher (WOO!)
>
> CTRL + Alpha keys:
>
> Ctrl+A: Market (edit: this opens the "add to home screen" menu for me)
>
> Ctrl+P: Settings
>
> Ctrl+W: Wallpaper
>
> Ctrl+M: Apps
>
> In Browser: (edit: these work in other apps too, if they apply)
>
> Ctrl+B: Bookmarks
>
> Ctrl+A: Select all
>
> Ctrl+C: Copy
>
> Ctrl+V: Paste
>
> Ctrl+W: Close current tab
>
> Ctrl+T: Open new tab
>
> Command/Windows button + : (edit: these commands work from anywhere,
>   even in other apps)
>
> Win+E: Launch Default Email App (brings up a choice dialog if
>   necessary)
>
> Win+A: Launch Calculator.apk
>
> Win+S: Launch Messaging.apk (SMS App)
>
> Win+C: Launch Contacts
>
> Win+B: Launch Browser.apk (not your default browser, unfortunately)
>
> Win+P: Launch Music.apk (not your default music player, unfortunately)
>
> Win+L: Launch Calendar
>
> Win+M: Launch Google Maps

Comment: @Al Are ICS and CM9 that much different now that we shouldn't tag both? Or was the original a feature of CM7 and not stock?

Comment: As far as I know that was a CM feature only.

Comment: Gotcha. I was unaware! Thanks for the tag revision then :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also assign your custom application to Search+key:

[ Source: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=26105269&postcount=3 ]

1. Must be using either nova or apex launcher
2. Long press on home screen and select shortcuts
3. Select activities (for whichever launcher you are using nova or apex)
4. Scroll down and select settings
5. Scroll down and select Quick Launch (the first one) and it should create the shortcut icon on your desktop